# Is there prime number of the form$1101001000100001000001.....$after the trivial one $k(0)=11$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let

- $k(0)=11$
- $k(1)=1101$
- $k(2)=1101001$
- $k(3)=11010010001$
- $k(4)=1101001000100001$
- And So on....

  I've checked it up to $k(120)$, and I did't find anymore prime of such form. Are there anymore prime numbers of that form ? (I just realized that only $k(6n+5)$ could be a prime (?))

Comment: I think you have an off-by-one error, Peter.  Letting `k[b_][n_] := 
 FromDigits[Flatten[{1, 1}~Join~Riffle[Map[0 & /@ Range[#] &, Range[n]], 1]~Join~If[n != 0, {1}, {}]], b]`, then searching k=1...100 via `Position[PrimeQ /@ k[10] /@ Range[100], True]` gives `{{35}}`.

Comment: Well, we can be sure that $k(n)$ will never be prime for all $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$. Also, we have that $11\nmid k(n)_{n>0}$

Comment: @evanb You are right, it is $k(35)$ with $667$ digits

Comment: Actually I am incorrect $-$ it should be that $11\nmid k(n)$ for $n$ odd. And, if $n$ is even, $11\mid k(n)$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher But $k(35)$ is prime, check which numbers are calculated by your program.

Comment: @Peter. Yes, you are right. Code should have been `a = FoldList[#1 10^#2 + 1 &, 1, Range[122]][[
  3 ;;]]; Or @@ (PrimeQ /@ a)` (there was a superfluous `1` in the beginning).

Comment: Also, an important clarification:  what base are these numerals written it?  In base 10, 11 is prime, but 11 is prime in bases 2 (which seems the most likely alternative), 4, 6, ... also!

Comment: Upto $n=199$, there is no further prime.

Comment: @evanb True, but this must be mentioned in the question in this case. Without any additional context, a decimal expansion is the most reasonable guess. And in the binary case, $1101$ is prime

Comment: With PARI/GP I could prove the primality of $k(35)$. If another prime exists, it must have more than $20\ 000$ digits.

Comment: The problem is base dependent.  Some posted answers interpret it as base 2!

Answer (score 5):

The formation law is clearly

$$
n_k = 2^k n_{k-1}+1
$$

with $n_1=3$

`n0 = 3;
For[i = 2, i < 50, i++, n1 = 2^i n0 + 1; 
 If[PrimeQ[n1], Print[n1, " ", IntegerString[n1, 2]]]; n0 = n1]`

obtaining

n = 13 -- 1101

n = 271302750695377321080849818469209754627603342031510693802940799730825845099036699701989532948734015220469369753358523432961 -- 11010010001000010000010000001000000010000000010000000001000000000010000000000010000000000001000000000000010000000000000010000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000010000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000001000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000001

If the number is considered in basis $10$ then the procedure is analogous. In this case we have $n_1 = 11$ and the recurrence equation is $n_k = 10^k n_{k-1}+1$ giving

`n = 1101001000100001000001000000100000001000000001000000000100000000001000000000001000000000000100000000000001000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000001000000000000000001000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000000100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000001 -- 1101001000100001000001000000100000001000000001000000000100000000001000000000001000000000000100000000000001000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000001000000000000000001000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000000100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000001`

Comment: *Clearly?* Well then, you sir have a good eye :)

Comment: In basis $2$ the multiplication by $2^k$ provides a left shift by $k$ places.

Comment: Hah, like a magician revealing their secret! I did not think to consider in base $2$. Good job! I cannot upvote as I have reached my daily voting limit, though, but well done :)

Comment: Is it clear that the numbers in the OP are given in base 2? It doesn't seem to say so anywhere.

Comment: The procedure is analogous. In this case we have $n_1 = 11$ and the recurrence equation is $n_k = 10^k n_{k-1}+1$. This case was attached to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer but might be of some help.

---

According to the "[Divisibility by $3$ Rule](http://www.softschools.com/math/topics/the_divisibility_rules_3_6_9/)," if $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$ then $k(n)$ will not be prime as it will be divisible by $3$. And, it will be [divisible by $11$](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10013.5.shtml) if $n$ is even.

That leaves only all the odd numbers for $n$ (since the congruence above is also even).

Comment: I think you mean that it leaves the congruence classes $3,5 \pmod 6$. For example, $1$ is congruent to $1$ mod 3 but is not even.

Comment: @JalexStark yes I probably did. I did not think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Mathematica search to answer your question:

```
b[1] = 1;
b[2] = 2;
b[n_] := b[n] = b[n - 1] + n - 1;
list[t_] := b /@ Range[t];
Reap@Do[a = ReplacePart[Array[0 &, b[t]], Transpose[{list[t]}] -> 1]; 
  c = FromDigits[a, 2]; If[PrimeQ[c], Sow@c], {t, 100}]
```

which yields

`{Null, {{3, 13, 
   2713027506953773210808498184692097546276033420315106938029407997308\
25845099036699701989532948734015220469369753358523432961}}}`

Comment: can you elaborate on the format of your output for those in the math.SE community who are not fluent in Mathematica?

Comment: Sorry... This question is first asked in mathematica community,When i answered it.

Comment: Yeah, just hoping you could explain so the answer will fit in its new home